# People say we are spiritually dead but doesn't our life come from God, therefore how can we be alive physically?

Tags: death, spiritual

People say we are spiritually dead but doesn't our life come from God, therefore how can we be alive physically if we are spiritually dead? On top of that I cannot find the phrase spiritual death anywhere in any Bible translation. Why didn't the disciples use the phrase spiritual death in any of their writings?

Comment: That is not quite true - see this question and my answer - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79973/luke-960-did-jesus-actually-encourage-the-man-to-bury-his-father/79975#79975

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Luke 9:60 Did Jesus actually encourage the man to bury his Father?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79973/luke-960-did-jesus-actually-encourage-the-man-to-bury-his-father)

Answer (score 1):

Two excellent Bible chapters for grasping how God sees people is in the prophetic writings of Ezekiel. He addressed his writing to physically living Jewish people held captive by the Chaldeans. He was one of them. Dates are given; historic events are mentioned, this is history that can be confirmed. The physically alive people are told by Ezekiel how God views them, and why God caused their captivity to happen. Basically, they had so violated God's covenant with them, to be his chosen nation, that he had allowed the Chaldeans to take them captive as divine punishment.

Now turn to chapter 22. Here are a few snippets to show how people who are physically alive can be viewed by God as spiritually 'dead'. "I have made thee a reproach to the heathen, and a mocking to all countries, near and far from thee shall mock thee... Behold, the princes of Israel, every one were in thee to their power to shed blood... Thou hast despised mine holy things, and hast profaned my sabbaths... and hath forgotten me, saith the Lord God... Son of man, the house of Israel is to me become dross: all they are brass, and tin, and iron, and lead, in the midst of the furnace; they are even the dross of silver... so will I gather you in mine anger and in my fury, and I will leave you there and melt you... Her priests have violated my law, and have profaned mine holy things: they have put no difference between the holy and the profane, neither have they shewed difference between the unclean and the clean... Therefore I have consumed them with the fire of my wrath..."

See how God uses language that humans can understand to teach them how he views their spiritual standing before him? They had to exist physically, and be guilty of profaning God's holy laws before they could be punished, and become spiritually dead, as chapter 37 goes on to depict. The graphic language God now uses has switched but the point about having become spiritually dead in his eyes is unavoidable.

This is the vision of the valley of dry bones. This is how God views his now spiritually dead nation of Israel, at that time in history. The huge pile of dry bones filling the entire valley was a lifeless heap. But God said would 'speak' to them and cause them to arise. Bone would join to bone; sinew and flesh would be added by God, then skin and - finally - God would breathe his breath of life into those who had been [spiritually] dead, and they would live - a vast [spiritual] army.

Nobody could think this was about literal corpses becoming physically alive again! It is an illustration to teach a spiritual truth to the-then spiritually dead nation of Israel. But the principle applies throughout history. People are spiritually dead to God unless and until he breathes his spirit of life into them.

Just as physical life comes from God, so does spiritual life. Your question seems to be about which comes first. The Bible says nothing about spirit creatures becoming humans, but it has a great deal to say about human beings becoming spiritually alive to God. Jesus said God is not the God of the dead, but of the living. The context was humans who had lived on earth, died, but were still alive to God, like people of faith such as Abraham, Isaac and Jacob - read Matthew 22:32.

The apostle Paul spoke of presently living people being "dead in trespasses and sins" (Ephesians 2:5), and how Christians then physically alive had "died to sin" and so were now spiritually alive to God (1 Peter 2:24).

In every generation there have always been those whom God has granted spiritual life, through faith, so we cannot make a blanket coverage, as in the question, that "we are spiritually dead". No, there have always been those who were, and are, spiritually alive, even while they live in the body, on Earth.

The entire Bible deals with the physical life of humans, their physical death (due to sin - Romans 6:14) and spiritually alive humans on Earth, even before they get to heaven - Romans 6:22-23. Only God can do that.